# Simply, what is a way to print ascii character from binary values in python3?

Tags: python-3.x

For example if I had the value '00010010' how would a simple function just print it as "H"?

Other answer seem to be rather complicated or don't work at all

Comment: Why is the value 18 an H?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `chr` and `ord` classes to convert between numbers and characters. In this case, given a binary number, you'll also need to use the `int` class to convert from a binary string to a Python integer.

For example:

`>>> chr(int("00010010", 2))
'\x12'`

This gives the ascii character of the given input. Note that the binary "00010010" does not correspond to a "H" character in ASCII; the value of "H" can be found with the `ord` function:

`>>> bin(ord("H"))
'0b1001000'`

Comment: Thanks, also just asking would there be any easy way to reverse a string? 
For example if :
string = "00010010"
and I wanted string2 = "01001000" ?

Ive tried string2 = string[-1::] but it seems to give me 0
-Whoops blunder, ignore this